# Does the Raspberry run groovy?

Tags: software-development

Is it possible to install [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) on the Raspberry Pi?

Will it run at a reasonable speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes it does**

To install on Raspbian just do:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk groovy
```

**Current JVM problem**

If you use Oracles Java Soft float implementation there are less issues to expect and a way better performance then with OpenJDK. Because Groovy focus its testing on Oracles VM, but Bugs found because of OpenJDK are fixed, too. But you will need a soft float distribution like Debian (not Raspbian) to get the Oracle VM working.

A hard float Oracle VM will be released, but there is no release date yet. See [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=11671&start=50) forum thread for more updates on that. Just be patient.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been able to run Groovy using the latest version of Raspbian, the Oracle JDK 8 beta that can be found [here](http://jdk8.java.net/fxarmpreview/) and [GVM](https://github.com/gvmtool/gvm) The performance is poor for interactive usage, but good enough if you are planning on running a groovy script as a cron job. For example a script I run every night takes about 10 seconds to execute on a desktop machine, 25 seconds to execute on a netbook, and 55 seconds on the raspberrypi.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Oracle JVM 8 (public beta) it even runs with hard floating point. Just gave it a try - it's not too slow!

http://javafx.steveonjava.com/javafx-on-raspberry-pi-3-easy-steps/